# Save the output as csv file from VScode programmatically

Tags: sql, csv, visual-studio-code, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My Requirement: Save the SQL query output (received the data) in to the local drives in csv file format.

My OS: Windows 10 64 bit
VS Code 1.67.1:
I have installed the following extensions to connect with snowflake data warehouse:

1. SQL Tools
2. Snowflake driver for SQL Tools

I have successfully connected my snowflake (cloud) data warehouse and received the data at
the VS code.

What I want is to save (export) the output (received the data) to the local file (for example to D:\result\result.csv).

How can I achieve that?

image attached for your reference.

thank you all.
pmk

Comment: Have you tried using the `COPY INTO` and `GET` command?  I don't know if the SQL Tools connector supports it directly, but most of the Snowflake connectors support this.

Comment: Yes. I created internal stage and save the output in csv file format. But could not able to get the data into local drive. I like to know can I use GET command in VScode? or any other method is there to extract the data into local drives? thanks

Comment: I tried using GET (and PUT command also) command.                                                 
 GET @MY_INTERNAL_UNLOAD_STAGE file://D:\CSV_DATA_RECEIVED.CSV;                         But I got the error "Unsupported feature unsupported_requested_format:snowflake".

Answer (score 0):

If you can run a bit of python, this does pretty much what you need

```
import snowflake.connector
import csv

conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='',
    password='',
    account='',
    warehouse='',
    database='',
    schema='',
    role=''
 )


results = conn.cursor().execute("""MY QUERY""").fetchall()


csvfile = open(r"PATH TO FILE",'a', newline='')
output = csv.writer(csvfile)
output.writerows(results)
csvfile.close
```

Comment: I have to code in command prompt. So, I used the following snowsql syntax: snowsql -a myorganization-myaccount -u jsmith -f /tmp/input_script.sql -o output_file=/tmp/output.csv -o quiet=true -o friendly=false -o header=false -o output_format=csv  . Put all the create format, create internal stage, copy into staging and get the data to local directory (GET) commands in a single .sql file together. I execute the above command gave me the result (automation - batch file). Thanks to you and all. Anyone can refer the URL: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html

Comment: Instead of giving account info using -a <account_name> and -u <username>, I have given the connection name which was I already added in the config file. Remaining commands are same as above.